# Is there a way to index and search all data on my phone?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, search

After taking a look at my options, I settled for Android-Sync to sync the Nexus with Outlook.

One of the issues I have, though, is that [Android-Sync](http://www.android-sync.com/) in its Notes and Tasks applications doesn't support...

- autocompletion
- last modified date

...which means it's a pain to locate items and it forces users to scroll down the whole list and try to find the item they're looking for.

Is there a way to index and search any data on the phone, even apps that don't ship with the Nexus by default?

Comment: App recommendations are off-topic per [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions).

Comment: @Flow: Looks like the question has been edited to ask for a solution rather than an app.

Comment: Is there a missing link between the introduction and the actual question?

Comment: @Flow - I am interested in the reasoning behind no app recommendations, if you can elaborate? Isn't this just asking for a solution, where - like most other questions - there could be more than one?

Comment: The close reason is "too localized" not because it's a off-topic app recommendation (which it is not as it stands now after the question got edited).